# logic gate simulation in c

Tags: c, recursion

```
 struct gate
    {
        char name[10]; 
        int type; //Type of the gate : INPUT,AND, OR, NOT, FLIPFLOP
        int value;
        char inputname1[10];
        char inputname2[10];
        struct gate *input1;
        struct gate *input2;
    };
```

I've created a tree with a struct structure, but I can't find out how to calculate it in a recursive way, can you help?

[image: schema]

```
int pre(struct gate *root)        //address of root node is pass
{
    if(root->input1->type==INPUT || root->input2->type==INPUT){
        if(root->type == OR){
            root->type = INPUT;
            return root->value = gateor(root->input1->value,root->input2->value);
        }
        if(root->type == AND){
            root->type = INPUT;
            return root->value = gateand(root->input1->value,root->input2->value);
        }
        if(root->type==NOT){
            root->type=INPUT;
            return root->value = gatenot(root->input1->value);
        }
        if(root->type == FLIPFLOP){
            root->type = INPUT;
            return root->value = gateflipflop(root->input1->value,0);
        }
    }

    pre(root->input1);
    pre(root->input2);

}
```

i can't think recursive,I was hoping it would work.

a,b,c,d is a struct but it only has value , type and name.
values are 1 and 0
gate values = -1;
I don't know if these values ​​are necessary.

Comment: Tip: Be very careful when using super tiny character buffers like `char name[10]`. It's probably better to use `char* name` instead and dynamically allocate labels at the required length.

Comment: You need to evaluate the inputs *before* evaluating the output.

Comment: Note that a flipflop is not a combinatorial item (it maintains a state), so it doesn't quite fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursively you could solve it like this:

```
int pre (struct gate *root) {
    if (root->type == INPUT)
        return root->value; // This is the recursion end
    else if (root->type == OR) {
        return gateor(pre(root->input1), pre(root->input2)); // Recurse here
    } else if (root->type == AND) {
        return gateand(pre(root->input1), pre(root->input2));
    } // Same for the other operations
}
```

This should give you an idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: The last `gateor` should be `gateand`, shouldn't it?